# txt file to zip file

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a simple text file named as 'file.txt'

I want to create a .zip file which **only** include that 'file.txt'. 
I tried `cat file.txt | zip newZipFun.zip -@`. But it compressed my parent folder.

Additionally I need to output my .zip to a different location too.

Comment: Why not just `zip newZipFun.zip file.txt`? Why are you trying to pipe the content of a file into `zip`?

Comment: I tried 'zip file.txt newZipFun.zip' and gives me three warning messages and saying "zip error : Zip file structure invalid (file.txt)"

Comment: It's the other way around: `zip [archive_name] [file to add]`

Comment: What @Bacon said.  Also, [read the fine manual](https://xkcd.com/293/) and you will learn these things for yourself.  `man zip` would have shown you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't just do `zip newZipFun.zip file.txt` as larsks suggested, you can imagine doing

```
 find . -name "toto*" |  xargs zip totos.zip
```

where "toto*" is the name of all files starting with toto, in the current working directory and it's sub directories